# How to track firebase push notification open count

Tags: firebase, push-notification

I have created ios and android application and it works fine with push notification.
But in FCM dashboard, I cannot see `Open` count even though I have already opened lots of push notification messages in foreground and background modes.

[image]

- Need to track open count so report page should show the `Open` count

Comment: Anybody finds answer for this please reply.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to go into Google Analytics (not FCM), find the event (notification_open) and mark it as a conversion.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069